# Why is the weight painting changing?

Tags: rigging

I imported an obj model from DAZ (attached). Why the purple vertex? why do i go painting bone after bone and when i get to the top and go back to see the function of the first one it is different(weight influence changes?).  Can any wiz help me? Earlier, the way i got around the purple vert was to go back assign zero weight to each bone and start all over again. it worked until i went back to check movement just to see it was all changed again.

[image: FIRST]D

[image: SECOND]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLpZe.png)

Here's the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: the reason for so many bones is that my clients spinal deformities take so many possibilities in terms of curves. thats why so many bones

Comment: What else do I have to do to get anyone's recommendations?? im so frustrated no one tipped anything...

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)